# Get back data after Json parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

In my iOS app I've to parse a JSON file. From this JSON I need the following stuff: name, image width and image height. To get image name I'ven't any problem, to get image with and height I use the following code:

```
- (void) loadImageFromWeb:(NSString *)urlImg forName:(NSString*)name {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImg];
    //NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSString *authCredentials =@"reply:reply";
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authCredentials base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   imageWidth = image.size.width;
                                   imageHeight = image.size.height;
                                   imgWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", imageWidth];
                                   imgHeight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", imageHeight];
                                   self.dictWithDataForPSCollectionView = @{@"title": name,
                                                                            @"width": imgWidth,
                                                                            @"height": imgHeight};
                                   [self.arrayWithData addObject:self.dictWithDataForPSCollectionView];
                                   NSLog(@"DATA ARRAY: %@", self.arrayWithData);
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
                               }

                           }];
}
```

You can see that I save the name, image width and image height in a NSDictionary then I put this in an NSMutableArray. When it execute the `NSLog`, I see this:

```
DATA ARRAY: (
        {
        height = "512.000000";
        title = "Eau de Toilet";
        width = "320.000000";
    },
        {
        height = "1049.000000";
        title = "Eau de Toilet";
        width = "1405.000000";
    }
)
```

My question is how to get this information back in the class who call my json parser, I tried to access to the variable in this way:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    recivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [recivedData appendData:data];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", string);
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *json;
    NSError *err;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:recivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];
    JsonCategoryReader *reader = [[JsonCategoryReader alloc]init];
    [reader parseJson:json];
}
```

But when I run the code it shows me an empty array. How I can have the information in this class?

UPDATE:
The JSON I've to parse is the following:

```
{
   "1":{
      "entity_id":"1",
      "type_id":"simple",
      "sku":"EAU_DE_TOILET_1",
      "description":"A passionate scent with the zest of exclusive Zegna Bergamot, sparked by Violettyne Captive, and the warmth of Vetiver and Cedarwood",
      "short_description":"EAU DE TOILETTE NATURAL SPRAY",
      "meta_keyword":null,
      "name":"Eau de Toilet",
      "meta_title":null,
      "meta_description":null,
      "regular_price_with_tax":60,
      "regular_price_without_tax":60,
      "final_price_with_tax":60,
      "final_price_without_tax":60,
      "is_saleable":true,
      "image_url":"http:\/\/54.204.6.246\/magento8\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/0\/image\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/p\/r\/product_100ml.png"
   },
   "2":{
      "entity_id":"2",
      "type_id":"simple",
      "sku":"EAU_DE_TOILET_2",
      "description":"A passionate scent with the zest of exclusive Zegna Bergamot, sparked by Violettyne Captive, and the warmth of Vetiver and Cedarwood",
      "short_description":"EAU DE TOILETTE NATURAL SPRAY",
      "meta_keyword":null,
      "name":"Eau de Toilet",
      "meta_title":null,
      "meta_description":null,
      "regular_price_with_tax":60,
      "regular_price_without_tax":60,
      "final_price_with_tax":60,
      "final_price_without_tax":60,
      "is_saleable":true,
      "image_url":"http:\/\/54.204.6.246\/magento8\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/0\/image\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/s\/c\/scheda_non_shop.jpg"
   }
}
```

My method `parseJson` do the following:

```
- (void)parseJson:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict {

    // Controllo che il json sia stato ricevuto
    if (jsonDict) {
        self.nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.imgUrlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.dictWithDataForPSCollectionView = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        self.arrayWithData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [self createArrayWithJson:jsonDict andIndex:1];
        [self createArrayWithJson:jsonDict andIndex:2];
}

- (void)createArrayWithJson:(NSDictionary*)json andIndex:(NSString*)i {
    NSDictionary *products = [json objectForKey:i];
    NSString *name = [products objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *imgUrl = [products objectForKey:@"image_url"];
    // Scarico l'immagine e calcolo le dimensioni
    if (name != nil && imgUrl != nil) {
        [self loadImageFromWeb:imgUrl forName:name];
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I did

Comment: you want the response data from the out side of the service hit class right?

Comment: You need to wait the async request completion before using data from arrayWithData. Does "[reader parseJson:json];" have such sync?

Comment: @Alex: I guessed that, but how I can wait for this request?

Comment: You can implement you own callback method or block in JsonCategoryReader or if "[reader parseJson:json];" is used in bg thread you can use sync image loading.

Comment: @Alex: Can you post here an answer with a code snipped so I can understand it better?

Comment: If I understood you correctly: you have a dictionary of "objects" (from your original JSON). For each object in "objects" you want to retrieve the "name" and "url" and asynchronously load an image. If the image is loaded, you want to create a new dictionary "image" with properties "hight", "width" and "title" and then insert this dictionary into the original JSON representation "objects". When everything is finished, you want to be notified. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happen is that your class is make before that your json is download, for have a good sequence you have to call your method for parse the json inside the completionHandler block, when you are sure that it is download. then when you have your object load you can parse it like this example:

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in  reader.arrayWithData){

     NSLog("height:  %@",[dic objectForKey:@"height"]);
     NSLog("title: %@",[dic objectForKey:@"title"]);
     NSLog("width: %@",[dic objectForKey:@"width"]);

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work... Indeed if I try to check what's stored in my `reader.arrayWitData` it has no value. I think it's because I'm populating it in an another thread...

Comment: ok but your method parseJson: what do can you share the code?

Comment: I read it now, but how I can solve this problem? What do you think if I do so: 1. call the method `parseJson` from the first class 2. parse Json with the second class 3. pass to the first class the name and the image url 4. in the first class I connect to the pic to get height and width?

Comment: when you create your object reader you have to use loadImageFromWeb:forName: for load it or your get a nil object because doesn't have anything inside

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40948/discussion-between-lucgian841-and-mirko-catalano)

Comment: I cannot see how the suggest answer can solve this problem. Can you explain @MirkoCatalano, please?

Comment: the problem was that him call the method for load him object with the json, before that the asynchrony block ended to download it, for that it was nil

Comment: if you call the method inside the completionHandler so when you know for sure that your json is download then everything works

Comment: Still, I'm confused: where is the JSON which is downloaded? Which async method finishes before what? Where is the JSON parsed? Your answer references these all, but I don't see any relationship to the question. What I do see however, that *image data* will be downloaded and a dictionary will be created containing a few meta data properties of the image. Downloading the images, seems to be driven from a JSON, which seems to exist before the first image will be downloaded.